# Customize SearchView(or CheckBox) without colorAccent attribute

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have SearchView, RadioButton and CheckBox in my app, they look like this:

**Search:**
[image]

**RadioButton:**

[image]

**CheckBox:**

[image]

What I want is to change SearchView's underline color to white and CheckBox and RadioButton color to green. But all those properties are assigned via `colorAccent` property of Material Theme. Is there a way to style those widgets separately?

Comment: `accentColor` is the standard way to colorize your UI, if you want to differ from official standards, just create a custom `Style` and use it manually.

Comment: @shkschneider search view is not easy to customise, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I know, but the standard being what it is, if you want to diverge from it: custom style. I don't see a way to avoid it. It's standard.

Comment: @shkschneider I get it, but search view doesn't have this property according to docs, the only way is use colorAccent. That's what I'm asking: how to style search view without specifying colorAccent.